# Sentry tries to unminify code that isn't minified and shows an Invalid Absolute Path URL error

Tags: sentry, false-positive, unminify

I'm trying to work on a new nodejs project and want to use Sentry for error logging.
I use a self hosted Sentry installation on the latest version and the official @sentry/node npm module.
While trying to implement Sentry by using the example code in their documentation I get an error in the sentry dashboard.

"We've encountered 1 problem un-minifying your applications source code!"
"Invalid Absolute Path URL"

When clicking on Read Guide I get sent to a [help page](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/sourcemaps/troubleshooting_js/#verify-artifact-names-match-stack-trace-frames) about uploading source maps.
However the code isn't minified and because of that I don't have a source map that I can upload.
I did notice a difference between using commonjs and es6.
When using es6 I get the error above but when using commonjs I still get an error about unminifying code but it shows a different error below it which is: "Sentry not part of build pipeline".
This error also directs me to a [guide](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/sourcemaps/#uploading-source-maps-to-sentry) but that guide also talks about source maps.
When using es6 I don't see any source code but when using commonjs I do get to see the source code which doesn't look minified.

I want the source code to be shown when using es6, what am I doing wrong here?

See the code I use below, when switching between commonjs to es6 I comment the require, uncomment the import and change the package.json to set the type to module.

```
const Sentry = require("@sentry/node");
// or use es6 import statements
// import * as Sentry from '@sentry/node';

Sentry.init({
  dsn: "dsn here",

  // Set tracesSampleRate to 1.0 to capture 100%
  // of transactions for performance monitoring.
  // We recommend adjusting this value in production
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
});

const transaction = Sentry.startTransaction({
  op: "test",
  name: "My First Test Transaction",
});

setTimeout(() => {
  try {
    foo();
  } catch (e) {
    Sentry.captureException(e);
  } finally {
    transaction.finish();
  }
}, 99);
```

[Sentry error with es6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrEgh.png)
[Sentry error with commonjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUuCf.png)

I tried to follow the [Sentry documentation](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/node/) from scratch and followed the getting started steps to make sure no other code would be affecting the results.
I did follow the "Add Readable Stack Traces to Errors" part but it eventually asked for build artifacts which I don't have because the code isn't being built/minified.